# Why Does Crowding Out Only Shift The Supply Curve

Tags: macroeconomics

In the demand for loanable funds I believe the explanation for when the government runs a deficit is that public saving becomes negative(because G>T), so national saving decreases and the supply curve shifts left. Apparently, even though the government is selling bonds to fund the deficit, the MFLF's demand curve is only defined to be for private investments/borrowing and so increased government borrowing only decreases the supply for these funds. Mankiw gives another converse explanation that, if instead the supply curve were defined to be only from private sources, then government borrowing would shift the demand right and would result in an equivalent higher real interest rate. What I don't understand though is how or why the MFLF is not defined so that both curves consist of both private and public pieces of both borrowing and saving? Why is one private and the other private and public, and wouldn't it otherwise be the case that a government deficit would shift both curves? My apologies if I misinterpreted this concept. Thanks